# How do I run jQuery on Wordpress site when I don't have SFTP access?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add some simple jQuery functionality to our Wordpress site, however I don't have SFTP access to the actual files. We maintain our own site, but do not have **SFTP access to** (bold added to clear up miscommunication) the server **due to use being a branch facility**. Can I just add the Google CDN to one of the php pages and then use `<script>` on the local page as needed?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: "We maintain our own site, but do not have server access." That sounds very strange to me. Technically yes, you can host the JS file elsewhere and simply modify your `functions.php` file to include an additional `wp_enqueue_script()` line to include additional JS files, but that defeats the purpose of having your own site, right? My question is: are you using wordpress.org for your WP site, or a self-hosted version?

Comment: It is self-hosted, though through our university system. As such, our student organization does not have FTP access, as the basic account was set up for us and we only have access to the Wordpress admin. We are trying to add some accordion styling, and a couple other simple components.

Comment: not ideal but nothing preventing you adding script in the templates through admin

Answer (score 2):

Just log in to wp-admin of your WordPress site, go to Appearance > Editor and drop a wp_enqueue_script() to the CDN location of the script you are wanting to use in the functions.php file of the theme.